# vim: How do I replace a character under my cursor with previously yanked text (more than once)?

Tags: vim, replace

Let's say I've yanked 3 characters "foo" into my clipboard by using a visual select + yank, ie: 'vllly'

Then I've moved my cursor to another character (let's call this character x) on line 5 which I'd like to replace with what I yanked previously, namely foo.

I can use 'p' to paste foo after x, or 'P' to paste foo before x, but I want to *replace* x with foo.

I can use 'vp' to replace x with foo, but this only works once, as it leaves me with x in my clipboard. In other words, if I move to my next occurrence of x and hit vp again, it doesn't replace it with foo.

Sure, I could do a search / replace by using :s/x/foo/gc and then ignoring all occurrences of x that I don't wish to replace, but this is a little tedious to type, particularly when all I need to do is replace 2 or 3 occurrences of x that are very close to my cursor but not on the same line (ie: lines 2, 3 and 7).

So currently I'm using :2,7s/x/foo/gc but I wonder if there is a way to move my cursor to x and hit [insert magic button here] to replace it with foo. And then I can move to my next occurrence of x and hit [magic button] again and boom, it's replaced x with foo again.

As much as it pains me to use this analogy, imagine you're typing in notepad, and you select 3 characters, hit Ctrl+c to copy them into your clipboard, and then highlight x, and hit Ctrl+v to replace it with foo. Then you highlight another x, and hit Ctrl+v again, and so on.

How do I do this in vim?

Comment: I think you'll find the best options here: http://superuser.com/questions/321547/how-do-i-replace-paste-yanked-text-in-vim-without-yanking-the-deleted-lines

Comment: Did you mean `lll` or `hhh` rather than `kkk`? `k` is *up*.

Comment: Yup I meant lll my bad, thanks @ChrisMorgan

Answer (score 52, accepted):

What about `s<C-r>0`, this can be repeated with `.`

- `s` deletes the character under the curser and puts you into insert mode.
- `<C-r>0` inserts register 0, which holds the yanked text.

You can also use `s` and type `foo` manually, which is also repeatable with `.`

Comment: That's nice. 1. I always use `cl` (didn't realize `s` does that), 2. I habitually use `"0` and it never occurred to me that I could postpone that to insert mode. I user i_CTRL-R on a daily basis already

Answer (score 7):

Paste from the 0 register with `v"0p`.

Comment: Thanks for this, it works great. However I chose Stefan's answer above as I found it easier to type.

Answer (score 2):

Copy your "foo" into another register, e.g. register a:

> "ay

Then visually select the character you want to replace with "foo" and press

> "aP

Answer (score 0):

This is less than ideal, but if you yank to named buffer `a` (eg yank with `"ay`), you can use `x"aP`.   Use your favorite map to make it a single keystroke.

Answer (score 0):

I need this so often, I wrote a plugin for that: [ReplaceWithRegister](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2703).

This plugin offers a two-in-one `gr` command that replaces text covered by a {motion}, entire line(s) or the current selection with the contents of a register; the old text is deleted into the black-hole register, i.e. it's gone.